# Logistic mapping in gnuplot

Tags: mapping, gnuplot, logistics

I have quite big problem when it comes to plotting data. 
First, I've obtained file data.dat from my c++ program, which implements the [logistic map](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

Data.dat looks as follows: first column should be the number k which should be on the bottom of the plot. When k is in the range [2,3) everything is fine, there is only one attractor (corresponding value to each k, which is always in the range (0,1)), but when it's [3,4) things get complicated.
For each point k there are 2 up to 100 points corresponding to each k.
Each of these points is in the separate column, but I have no idea how could I connect those to certain k.

[image: Here is the image of what I'm trying to obain]

Here is a sample of my data for points: 2.5, 3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.8 and 3.99999, divided by the newline for clarity (it's not divided by a newline in my original data file)

http://pastebin.com/2AcAjXzk

Thanks for any help, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot cannot handle such a data format properly. Either modify your program such that it prints in each line the `k` followed by a single value, or you process your data file with a short `awk` script before plotting:

```
plot '< awk ''{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $i}'' file.txt' using 1:2 with dots notitle
```

Comment: Working as expected, thanks for your help, appreciated.

Comment: It seems that gnuplot *can* handle this data format: `plot for [i=2:100] 'file.txt' u 1:i with dots lc rgb 'red' notitle`. Gnuplot simply ignores if some lines have less than 100 columns. I don't know if it's efficient at all, but, at least, it does the job :)